# Cannot use ng-repeat inside a directive's template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I cannot make my ng-repeat to work inside the directive template. It shows as "ngRepeat: day in days track by $index".

```
    angular
        .module('Auto')
        .directive('calendar', CalendarDirective);
```

```
CalendarDirective.$inject = ['$interpolate'];
CalendarDirectiveController.$inject = ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$attrs', '$location'];

function CalendarDirective($interpolate) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: true,
        template: $('#template-calendar').html(),
        replace: true,
        link: function(scope, element) {
            var startSym = $interpolate.startSymbol();
            var endSym = $interpolate.endSymbol();
            var rawExp = element.html();
            var transformedExp = rawExp.replace(/&lt;@/g, startSym).replace(/@&gt;/g, endSym);
            var parsedExp = $interpolate(transformedExp);
            scope.$watch(parsedExp, function(newValue) {
                element.html(newValue);
            });
        },
        controller: CalendarDirectiveController,
    };
}

function CalendarDirectiveController($scope, $rootScope, $attrs, $location) {
    $scope.monthText = moment().format('MM YYYY');
    $scope.days = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'];

    $scope.title = function () {
        return 'Directive';
    }
}
```

<script type="text/html" id="template-calendar">
<div>
    <table>
        <thead>
        <tr ng-repeat="day in days track by $index">
            <th><@day@></th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

I'm currently out of ideas

[Here is the plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/7HEvXbQDU2wUJ00i?open=lib%2Fscript.js&deferRun=1)

Comment: do you able to reproduce it in some plunker/fiddle?

Comment: [Here is the plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/7HEvXbQDU2wUJ00i?open=lib%2Fscript.js&deferRun=1)

Comment: you already have `$interpolateProvider`, why do you need to do any work in `link`? https://plnkr.co/edit/F39xc4TrlCMACHon?open=lib%2Fscript.js&deferRun=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$interpolateProvider` already does the job, a.e.

```
angular.module('plunker', [], function($interpolateProvider) {
        $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('<@');
        $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('@>');
})
```

So you don't need a `$watch` inside a `link`.

```
function CalendarDirective($interpolate) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: true,
        template: $('#template-calendar').html(),
        replace: true,
        link: function(scope, element) {
           // removed 
        },
        controller: CalendarDirectiveController,
    };
}
```

<kbd>[Plunker Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/F39xc4TrlCMACHon?open=lib%2Fscript.js&deferRun=1)</kbd>